# Properly unmounting a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Sorry I couldn't come up with a more specific title for this question. When I execute the below snippet I get the following warning:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Typewriter component.

However, if the render() in MyComponent is changed to the following, I get no such warning:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <Typewriter />
        { this.state.render == 1 && "Render 1" }
        { this.state.render == 2 && "Render 2" }
        { this.state.render == 3 && "Render 3" }
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I properly unmount this rendered Typewriter component that itself is performing some mounting and unmounting actions? Thanks!

```js
class Typewriter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      finalText: ''
    }
    this.typeWriter = this.typeWriter.bind(this);
  }

  typeWriter(text, n) {
    if (n < (text.length)) {
      if (n + 1 == (text.length)) {
        let j = text.substring(0, n+1);
        this.setState({ finalText: j });
        n++;
      }
      else {
        let k = text.substring(0, n+1) + '|';
        this.setState({ finalText: k });
        n++;
      }
      setTimeout( () => { this.typeWriter(text, n) }, 100 );
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.typeWriter('testing_typewriter', 0);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.finalText }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      render: 1,
      update: false
    };
    this.interval = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setTimeout( () =>
      this.rendering(), 1700
    );
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.render < 3) {
      this.interval = setTimeout( () =>
        this.rendering(), 1200
      );
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.interval = null;
  }

  rendering() {
    if (this.state.render < 3) {
      if (this.interval) {
        this.setState({ render: this.state.render + 1 });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          { this.state.render == 1 && "Render 1" }
          { this.state.render == 2 && <Typewriter /> }
          { this.state.render == 3 && "Render 3" }
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I think your problem is that your parent component is attempting to replace the Typewriter component before the latter has completed its typewriter routine. I would suggest a "handshake" approach instead of using timers. You could for example define a `typingDone` function in the parent, then pass it as a prop to the Typewriter component, and have the later call that method when the typing is complete. The `typingDone` function could then trigger a change of child component by updating the state, for example.

Comment: You're using `clearInterval`. What you want is `clearTimeout`.

Comment: Also, in the Typewriter component you are not setting a reference to the `setTimeout` and clearing it in `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Why do you want to call `this.setState` from `componentWillUpdate()`. You should not ideally do it. What is the reason though?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by clearing the Timeout/Interval in the componentWillUnmount function

in the typewriter function you need to keep track of this timeout:

```
setTimeout( () => { this.typeWriter(text, n) }, 100 );
```

with something like

```
this._timer = setTimeout( () => { this.typeWriter(text, n) }, 100 );
```

Then add a lifecycle method:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.clearTimeout(this._timer);
}
```